# Connecting two PCBs at an acute angle

Tags: pcb

How to connect two PCB under the angle less than 90 degrees using stable connection (e.g. soldering)?

Comment: Use an angled connector. E.g. this one https://uk.rs-online.com/web/p/dimm-sockets/8962287/

Comment: Mechanical strain and bend are going to be really wonky. You might be able to weld two plates together but it would be interesting what material these PCBs are.

Comment: Use a box with channels for each PCB at the correct angle, and through-solder before or after sliding them in place. The channel would provide more strength and rigidity than would connectors or a seam along one side.

Comment: Do you actually need the PCBs to be electrically connected? Or can you just use a small hinge (maybe a tiny plastic hinge) and bolt it to the PCB and then use a flex cable to make the electrical connections? In particular, it would make it easier to unfold the PCBs for rework.

Comment: Use a connector - flat cable. search for FFC. And mechanically join the boards with a bracket.

Comment: Or if you want to show off and cost isn't an issue (hah!) you could take the FFC approach to an extreme and go for a flex or rigid-flex PCB design. Though IMO using either an FFC or a ribbon cable with IDC connectors should be both practical and economical enough.

Answer (score 2):

If you really need to solder it, one way to do this would to get some thick copper sheet metal, like 0.02" or 0.04", and and have a machinist put a bend in the copper at the angle needed. Put some thick pads on the board and solder the copper on.

The problem with this is you would need a lot of heat for the copper (with it's large thermal mass) which might not be good for the PCB. Pads on the PCB that are used with any kind of mechanical force can result in the pad being ripped from the board, so it's not advisable to use pads for mechanical purposes without strain relief.

It would probably be better to have a piece of metal machined and use fasteners to join the boards together.

Or you could put holes in the sheet metal and forget the soldering and use fasteners.

Another good option for fasteners are [SMT PEM nuts](https://catalog.pemnet.com/category/uts-and-spacers-standoffs-surface-mount-type-smtso)

[image]

Comment: In your mind, are these surface mounted? Because in my mind you would slice them and use them as through-hole (or through-slot) components due to the strain.

Comment: If I was soldering something to the board, yeah, surface mounted. If I was doing this myself, I would use a through hole with fasteners and a machined part.